# Prevent Vue.js from rendering component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My case is that I have a static component on the desktop and it must become carousel on mobile.
The component is rendered server side because of seo and I use `is="my-component"` to trigger vue on it. Typically when I duplicate the markup and check in `created()` the breakpoint, I can trigger some carousel constructor. However, if a breakpoint is set to desktop, vue will still rerender component which is redundant.

I know that one case may not be that effective, but I have *a lot of performance and parsing problems because of vue* in my previous project, so I need to keep performance in mind from the beginning.

Is it possible to somehow prevent rendering on `beforeCreate()` hook, but still be able to use it in some conditional?

Comment: Why not use `v-if`? Not clear what you're asking

Comment: I use `v-if` now, but it's still triggered **after** vue parse template. My point is to prevent whole vue logic on some beforeCreate hook.

Comment: Can you show that code? I'm still not clear what you mean

Comment: I'd really like to see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I have read your comment, and you would like to use something else that is not [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), I can think only in two ways of doing it.

**1)** If you are using `vue-router` you can run make use of [Lazy Loading Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk) which is basically a function that can return an `import('component')` (which is a promise).

MobileCarousel.ts

```
import { isMobile } from '@/utils/mediaQuery';

const MobileCarousel = (): Promise<Vue> | void => {
  if (!isMobile()) {
    return;
  }

  return import('@/components/MobileCarousel/MobileCarousel.vue');
};

export default MobileCarousel;
```

Routes.ts

```
import MobileCarousel from '@/components/MobileCarousel/MobileCarousel.ts';

...
{
  path: 'route-that-has-a-mobile-only-carousel',
  name: 'mobile-only-carousel',
  component: MobileCarousel,
},
enter code here
```

My only concern with this approach is related to the server-side rendering. As I never have played with server side-rendering with Vue I cannot assure you that it will work as you expect, you can give a try. Hope it helps you.

**2)** Apart from using Lazy Loading Routes, I believe that a Vue component with a [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) that returns only if it is mobile also can be useful for your case.